# Can I remove a character not having html tags or CSS class using CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to remove character that doesn't belong to any html tag, CSS id or class. For example I want to remove the "--" from the code given below. Please help me to understand how to do this.

```html
<span class="price">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>12.05</span> 
       -- 
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>19.36</span> 
   </span>
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "remove"? and `--` has the class = "price".

Comment: There is not a css selector for text nodes, so if you can't modify the html, use javascript, or something in addition to css, then you might be out of luck.

Comment: a work around could be a reset on font-size for that very example, but could be a problem elsewhere `.price {font-size:0;} .price span {font-size:1rem}`

Comment: Everything on the page has a tag. If it's not wrapped in a `span or div` tag it's most likely wrapped in the `html or body` tag.

Comment: You can't do it with CSS only with JS (Don't bother with workarounds), but as SalmanA wrote in the first comment - It's unclear what you're asking

Comment: @SalmanA Yes. your correct. I just realized "--" belongs to span class "price". I just want to get rid of "--".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to solve that is set font-size: 0 to .price and set font size for the inner spans. Something llike that:

```
.price { font-size: 0px;}
.amount { font-size: 16px;}
```

Havn't test it but i think it should work.

Comment: I think it should be `.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount`

Comment: @AlonEitan i edited to even shorter since the span is inside another one.

Comment: @A. Meshu Thank you. It worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

There aren't many ways to do that without JavaScript. One option is to set the font color as transparent for the parent element and specify another color for the children.

For example:

```
.price {
  color: transparent;
}

.price span {
  color: #000;
}
```